# Removing spaces from variable not working?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For some reason, the spaces from my variable are not being removed. Interestingly, a computer with an american locale works fine.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=File(s)" %%G in ('dir arbitray.7z ^| FIND "File"') do (
    set size=%%H
    set size=!size:~0,-3!
    set size=!size:,=!  
    set size=!size:.=!
    set size=!size: =!
    echo !size!
)
```

Output:

```
28 351 655
```

Desired output:

```
28351655
```

Seems that no matter how I format it,

```
set size=!size: =!
```

Doesn't seem to do anything.
Could it be that those "spaces" between the numbers aren't actually spaces? If so, how to I filter them out?

Comment: Are you trying to get the summary size of all files? `for /f "tokens=3" %%G in ('dir^|find "Datei(en)"') do set "size=%%G"` gets you the size part only (Note the `find` string is language dependent!). You just have to remove the dots and commas (you can do that outside the `for` loop with `set "size=%size:.="` and `set "size=%size:,=%"`). (and `delims` doesn't work as you seem to assume; It's a list of characters, not a string.)

Comment: Redirect your output to a file and examine the file with a hex editor to see precisely what characters are actually appearing.

Comment: Do you want to get the size of file `arbitray.7z`? Yes, open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read all output help pages. You can simply use `for %%I in (arbitray.7z) do set "size=%%~zI"` in batch file to get the file size of this file assigned to environment variable `size`.

Comment: Add /-c to the `dir` command. Or perhaps simply `for %%G in (arbitray.7z) do set "size=%%~zG"

Comment: @Magoo very good idea in both comments, but the last one was exactly what I wanted. Completely forgot about for %%G in (arbitray.7z) do set "size=%%~zG"

Comment: @Mofi Good answer, this was what I was looking for!

Comment: Option `delims=` delimits on characters instead of words. This is why you had to do awkward things to get it to work. Rather would have used `delims=) ` and use `%%I` instead of `%%H` if you had no better option than to do it this way. `find "File"` also could output other lines containing `File` making extra unneeded processing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the strings you are trying to capture and parse...